# Clicking through NSWindow/CALayer

Tags: objective-c, macos

So I'm working on an issue I have when trying to do some simple animation using CAKeyframeAnimation, and I believe my problem is more related to not fully understanding how NSWindow, NSView, and CALayer work together. 
I have two main objects in question. MyContainerWindow (NSWindow subclass) and MyMovableView (NSView subclass). My goal is to be able to animate MyMovableView back and forth across the screen, while maintaining the ability to click on anything through MyContainerWindow unless you are clicking on wherever MyMovableView is. I am able to accomplish the first part fine, by calling -addAnimation:forKeyPath: on myMovableView.layer, and everything is great except I can't click through MyContainerWindow. I could make the window smaller, but then the animation would clip by the bounds of the window.

Important points: 
1) MyContainerWindow is initWithFrame to [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame], NSBorderlessWindowMask, defer no, buffered
2) I setWantsLayer:TRUE to MyMovableView
3) MyContainerWindow is clear, and I want it to be as if there wasnt a window at all, but need it so I have a larger canvas to animate on.

Is there something obvious I'm missing to be able to click through an NSWindow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in this scenario was actually to use:

```
[self ignoresMouseEvents:YES];
```

I originally was hoping to be able to retain the mouse events on the specific CALayer that I'm animating, but upon some further research I understand this comes with the cost of custom drawing everything from scratch, which is not ideal for this particular project.